# Using numba on this function throws this error. What might be the issue?

Tags: python, initialization, nested-loops, jit, numba

This is the function which I am trying to accelerate. I am using spyder latest version which is using python 2.7 and Numba version is 0.38.0 -

```
@nb.njit(fastmath = True, parallel = True, error_model = "numpy", nogil = True)
def fun(a, b, c, d, ef):
    # start = time.time()
    m_d = np.array([-40, -40, -40])
    f = np.zeros((128, 128, 128), np.complex64)


    for i in range(0, len(d)):
        x = nb.int64(math.floor((ef[i][0] - m_d[0]) / 1.2))
        y = nb.int64(math.floor((ef[i][1] - m_d[1]) / 1.2))
        z = nb.int64(math.floor((ef[i][2] - m_d[2]) / 1.2))
        f[x][y][z] = complex(d[i])


    e  = 0
    g = np.zeros((128, 128, 128), np.complex64)
    X = Y = Z = 128

    for i in range(len(a)):
        x = a[i]
        y = b[i]
        z = c[i]
        for x2 in range(x - 1, x + 5):
            for y2 in range(y - 1, y + 5):
                for z2 in range(z - 1, z + 5):
                    if (-1 < x < X and
                        -1 < y < Y and
                        -1 < z < Z and
                        (x != x2 or y != y2 or z != z2) and
                        (0 <= x2 < X) and
                        (0 <= y2 < Y)and
                        (0 <= z2 < Z)):
                            q = f[x2][y2][z2]
                            di = np.sqrt((x - x2) ** 2 + (y - y2) ** 2 + (z - z2) ** 2) * 1.2
                            if di <= 6 and di >= 2:
                                e = 4
                            elif di > 6 and di < 8:
                                e = 38 * di - 224
                            elif di >= 8:
                                e = 80
                            else:
                                continue
                            value = q / (e * di)
                            g[x][y][z] = g[x][y][z] + value


    # print "fun : ", time.time() - start
    return g
```

The error is -

```
task = get()
TypeError: ('__init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)', <class 'numba.errors.LoweringError'>, ('Failed at nopython (nopython mode backend)\nreflected list(array(float32, 1d, C)): unsupported nested memory-managed object\n\nFile "test_numba_errorful.py", line 702:\ndef fun(a, b, c, d, ef):\n    <source elided>\n    # m_d = np.array([-40, -40, -40])\n    f = np.zeros((128, 128, 128), np.complex64)\n    ^\n[1] During: lowering "ef = arg(4, name=)"
```

After fixing some multiprocessing overhead, I am now getting this error -

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 360, in _compile_for_args
    raise e

LoweringError: reflected list(array(float32, 1d, C)): unsupported nested memory-managed object

File "test_numba_errorful.py", line 702:
def fun(a, b, c, d, ef):
    <source elided>
    # m_d = np.array([-40, -40, -40])
    f = np.zeros((128, 128, 128), np.complex64)
    ^
```

What is causing the error ? How can I rectify it ?

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. The `time` function is not supported within `nopython` mode jitted functions. See the list of supported python features here:

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html

2. You can only print using `print` as a function. You'll want to `from __future__ import print_function` when using python 2.

Changing the above two items allowed the code to work for me with guesses on the inputs (I tried just standard numpy arrays) using Numba 0.39. For the version that you are using though, it seems from the error like you might be using something like a list-of-lists or lists of numpy arrays, which wasn't supported in earlier versions.

Another general suggestion is that when dealing with multidimensional arrays, it's always better to access `x[i,j]` rather than `x[i][j]` in terms of performance.

Comment: Thanks @JoshAdel, But your 2nd poin gives this error - print "calci : ", time.time() - start
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Also time is not the issue, I have run after removing that. The same error is shown. I guess this is due to numba being 0.38.1 in my conda. I tried to update it using conda update numba but it didn't update. My spyder is using python 2.7 and spyder version is 3.2.8.